# How to replace HTML code using MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, html, find-and-replace

I’m trying to delete the CSS from my code using Word 2010. I’ve searched online on how to find and replace text, and tried some but none worked.
Below is the code i don't want.

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

```
<p><a href="$Sports_Book_Front_Side[2].jpg">
```

style="border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; background-image: none; border-bottom-width: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0px; display: inline; padding-right: 0px; border-top-width: 0px" border="0" alt="Sports Book" src="$Sports_Book_Front_Side_thumb.jpg" width="640" height="480">

I’m having trouble because I’m confused how to use the ‘wildcards’ in the search function in Word 2010. What would be a formula for this? Is there a ‘start with this string of characters and end with this string of characters’ formula I could use?

Comment: [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)